# Laptop Recommendation for Gaming Price-Affordablity Comparation

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards, processor

I'm looking for a laptop, I kept the price band a little wider.

I would like to share with you that I found 2-3 while researching. I would be glad if you are among these candidates or if you have different suggestions.
Prices are Turkish Liras to Dollar

- First One is Asus TUF DASH F15 FX517ZM-HN118 Ram=16gb Storage=512GB
  SSD CPU=Intel Core i7 12650H GPU=Rtx3060 Max-P Price=1.568,11 USD
- Second One is Asus TUF DASH F15 FX517ZR-HN013 Ram=16gb Storage=1TB
  SSD CPU=Intel Core i7 12650H GPU=Rtx3070 Price=2.056,48 USD
- Last One is Asus ROG Strix G16 G614JU-N3110 Ram=16gb Storage=521GB
  SSD CPU= Intel Core i7 13650HX GPU=Rtx4050 Price=1.874,48 ABD Doları